# Save button disappears when adding new in-app purchase in iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

For both non-consumable and consumable products, in the page of create new IAP product, I can't save the product because the save button disappeared after editing necessary information (price tier, product ID, description).

How to solve this problem?

Comment: This question has been bothering me for 2 hours...

Comment: User experience is really bad.

Comment: This just started happening for me today. Worked fine when I was adding IAPs yesterday. Today, following the same steps, the Add Language step causes the Save button to disappear permanently. Let's hope Apple fixes it soon.

Comment: Was also looking for a solution today. Clearly it's not just me, even after trying different browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a workaround until Apple fixes it:

- Login to iTunes Connect in Google Chrome
- Fill out all the form fields for your in-app purchase - ignore the fact the Save button disappears
- When the form is complete, open Chrome Developer Tools (F12 on Windows / Cmd+Opt+I on Mac)
- Open the Console tab and enter `document.forms['addonInitForm'].submit()`, then press return to submit the form

I dug around in the code of the page and it seems this is what the missing button should be doing. The button is actually there but it has height&width of 0px because the `<img>` element has no `src`/`width`/`height` attributes:

```
<img border="0" onclick="disableLCPageButton('saveChangesActionButton');document.forms['addonInitForm'].submit();" class="saveChangesActionButton" id="saveChangesActionButton" style="">
```

Comment: Nice, it works!! You saved my day! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the Application Loader and fill in new IAP manually there and it will work

Answer (score 1):

I've created video with the issue

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EPlRts5fy84&feature=youtu.be

Hope Apple will fix it soon it's annoying